# Twilio Call/recording Time Out

Tags: twilio

I am working in twilio call and recording process , everything going fine till the call goes below 1 hour , if it exceeds i got response like this 'i got TIMEOUT'

```
**[Called] => +18445184466

    [Digits] => timeout

    [RecordingUrl] => https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC0208c3ffe80b07bebe8ca07eea206179/Recordings/REc0726376f9485aa2005870bc6f9f3ce8**

   ......
```

Call disconnected after 1 hour even i set

```
$response->record(array('timeout' =>100000));
```

Please help how to achieve recording after 1 hour without call disconnect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When using [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) to record a call the maximum length by default is 1 hour. You can increase the maximum length of the recording by setting the [`maxLength` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-maxlength). This is set in seconds and by default is 3600 (one hour). You can set it up to the maximum length of a call: 14400, which is 4 hours.

```
$response->record(array('maxLength' => 14400));
```

Comment: Thank u ..but what's the use of timeout parameter?

Comment: The ['timeout' attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-timeout) tells Twilio to end the recording after a number of seconds of silence has passed. The default is 5 seconds.

Comment: Working Fine... Thank you :)

Comment: my problem is, i'm calling a twilio function from my twimil bin using the recordingStatusCallback in my record, but the function is called when there's silence, so I get application error in my function

Comment: @conterio I recommend you ask a new question with a full explanation of what you're doing and what errors you get. That will get you a much better chance of help than asking in the comment of a 6 year old question.